# Powering monitor display with Intel integrated graphics while running NVIDIA GPU, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, dvi

I'm building an Ubuntu PC with the following components:

- Intel i7-7700 CPU
- NVIDIA 1080 Ti GTX GPU
- MSI Z270 SLI motherboard. Has integrated graphics ports for HDMI and DVI.
- Ubuntu 16.04 OS

I'm struggling to navigate the inter-dependent web of software/hardware relationships that need to fall into place to get this thing running. Namely, to get the GPU running it seems that I need to configure CUDA and it's drivers [with the monitor running off of the motherboard's integrated graphics](http://abhay.harpale.net/blog/linux/nvidia-gtx-1080-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/).

The challenge is that I cannot run the monitor from the integrated graphics port with the GPU in the PCI slot. I've tried enabling the multi display option in the BIOS. Here's what `lspci` returns. Note that the only VGA compatible controller is the GPU:

```
~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 591f (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a2af
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a2b1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a2ba 
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a282
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a290 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a294 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c5 
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a2a1
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a2a3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b06 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10ef (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
```

I've tried installing the [Intel graphics driver](https://www.techzim.co.zw/2017/01/heres-guide-installing-intel-graphics-driver-ubuntu-16-04/) using a `.deb` file and the install just quits.

I have tons more questions, but can anyone help me get over this first hurdle? Do I take the GPU out, run the machine off the card to install it's drivers and enable multiple monitor display before plugging the GPU back in and enabling CUDA? I need the GPU for machine learning and want to keep it away from anything related to the system's graphical display.

Comment: No, you don't need to change outputs. You can boot with `nomodeset` and then install the Nvidia drivers. Cuda isn't required.

Comment: @MichaelBay Does booting with `nomodeset` create the same behavior as as `nouveau.modeset=0`? Because if so I'm already doing that from the GRUB (which I have to call up every time I boot) and getting the same results.

Comment: Not exactly the same. Nomodeset forces VESA mode that is always compatible but in low graphics mode. It allows to install the required proprietary drivers though.

Comment: @MichaelBay OK, so just `nomodeset` after the quiet splash line in the GRUB and from there I should be gtg for installing NVIDIA drivers. Question, though: can I use the GPU for computation and powering the monitor at the same time? It seems to me that I'm still going to want to switch the monitors to integrated graphics no matter what, right?

Comment: If you have no multi-monitor setting (or it doesn't work) then you have to work with the Nvidia card only.

Comment: @MichaelBay I do have a multi-monitor setting, which I turned on, but it's not working. I can access the BIOS and GRUB, but the screen goes blank when it's time to login.